# JAVA , i can´t delete empty folder

Tags: java, file, filesystems, directory

Hi could you help me? I have an empty folder.
I declare this folder like this

```
 File slozka= new File ("M:/ShareDirs_KSP/RDM_Debtors/DMS_PROD/ERMS/IN/42232471/");
```

after that i want delete this folder. But something is wrong

```
slozka.delete();
```

Folder is not deleted.

However, some folders i can delete with this code.
Any idea?
Thanx

Comment: Please [don't use the `File` class anymore](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It's outdated and uninformative. Use the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class instead. It will give you more information on why it fails (read the link).

Answer (score 0):

Java will not be able to see this `Mapped` directory - it is a windows thing that is based upon your Windows User name.

If you try to use the UNC file path and have permission then you should be able to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, directory deletion is possible only for empty directory. 2 possible reasons here:

1.**directory is locked by OS**;
 2. **directory is not empty**.

Delete method for case 2:

```
/**
 * Force deletion of directory
 * @param path
 * @return
 */
static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if (path.exists()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            } else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return (path.delete());
}
```

This one will delete your folder, even if non-empty, without troubles (excepted when this directory is locked by OS).

Answer (score -1):

maybe it's ll help you :

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```